# MailKit - How to get size of each attachment

Tags: c#, mailkit, mime-message

I want to format attachment info as a string with **File Name** and **File Size**

I can get **FileName** in `Attachments.ContentDisposition`, but **Size** is `null`. Is any other way to get?

Eg : `string.Join(',' + Environment.NewLine, mailData[i].Attachments.ToList().Select(y => y.ContentDisposition.FileName + '(' + y.ContentDisposition.Size.ToString() + ')').ToList())`

Example output i want :

`xxx.jpg(123 bytes),
xxx.png(456 bytes),
xxx.pdf(123456 bytes),`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no property that will get you the size (the `Size` property on `ContentDisposition` relies on the sending client to set that and even when set might not be accurate).

So to get the size of the attachment, you would need to do this:

```
static long MeasureAttachmentSize (MimePart part)
{
    using (var measure = new MimeKit.IO.MeasuringStream ()) {
        part.Content.DecodeTo (measure);
        return measure.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Will this download the attachment?

Comment: The above code snippet assumes you've already downloaded the attachment.